# Flutter release apk

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I would like to know if the apk file produced from running the `flutter run --release` command is different from `flutter build apk`. Which is better for uploading to the playstore.? I just tried both commands and the difference in apk size is really huge. The release command produces a far smaller apk size. 
In summary what I want to know is since
`Flutter build apk` =>> fat apk. 
 Does
`Flutter run --release` =>> split apk?

Comment: Flutter run release is used for production and flutter build apk is used for debug

Answer (score 9):

`flutter run --release:` builds a release version of the app and starts it directly, then shows the console UI to manipulate the running instance.source [flutter wiki](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/The-flutter-run-variants)

Use release mode for deploying the app, when you want maximum optimization and minimal footprint size. For mobile, release mode (which is not supported on the simulator or emulator), means that:

- Assertions are disabled.
- Debugging information is stripped out.
- Debugging is disabled.
- Compilation is optimized for fast startup, fast execution, and small package sizes.
- Service extensions are disabled.
  (apps are smaller)

`flutter build apk` results in a fat which is a single APK that contains binaries for multiple ABIs embedded within it. This has the benefit that the single APK runs on multiple architectures and thus has wider compatibility, but it has the drawback that its file size is much larger, causing users to download and store more bytes when installing your application. When building APKs instead of app bundles, it is strongly recommended to build split APKs

**Although app bundles are preferred over APKs, there are stores that don’t yet support app bundles**

When should I build app bundles versus APKs?

The Google Play Store recommends that you deploy app bundles over APKs because they allow a more efficient delivery of the application to your users. However, if you’re distributing your application by means other than the Play Store, an APK may be your only option.

read more [from the docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)

Comment: Thanks but does this mean the apk from flutter run --release is a split apk?

Comment: In order words, if i wanted a release version of my application installed on my device, i'd simply run `flutter run --release` and if i want to deploy (to play store), i'd run `flutter build appbundle`. Thanks

Comment: yes..and dont forget to sign your app for release to playstore

Comment: But what the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

You can split apks with this command

```
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
```